# Domain Driven Design - How to handle updates for parts of your aggregrate roots

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

**BACKGROUND:**    I have a Person domain object.  It is an aggregate root.  I have included a portion of the class below.

I am exposing methods to perform the objects behaviors.    For instance, to add a BankAccount I have the AddBankAccount() method.      I have not included all the methods of the class but suffice to say that any public property must be updated using a method.

I am going to create an IPerson repository to handle the CRUD operations.

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{ 
    void Save(Person p);
    //...other methods
}
```

**QUESTION**:  How do I tell the repository which fields need to be updated when we are updating an existing person?  For example,  If I add a bank account to an existing person how do I communicate this information to the repository when repository.Save() is called?

In the repository it is easy to determine when a new person is created, but when an existing person exists and you update fields on that person,  i'm not sure how to communicate this to the repository.

I don't want to pollute my Person object with information about which fields are updated.

I could have separate methods on the repository like .UpdateEmail(), AddBankAccount() but that feels like overkill.  I would like a simple .Save() method on the repository and it determines what needs to update in some manner.

How have others handled this situation?

I have searched the web and stackoverflow but haven't found anything.   I must not be searching correctly because this seems like something simple when it comes to persistence within the DDD paradigm.   I could also be way off on my understanding of DDD :-)

```
public class Person : DomainObject
{
    public Person(int Id, string FirstName, string LastName,
        string Name, string Email)
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.CreditCards = new List<CreditCard>();
        this.BankAccounts = new List<BankAccount>();
        this.PhoneNumbers = new List<PhoneNumber>();
        this.Sponsorships = new List<Sponsorship>();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public string LastName { get; private set; }
    public string Name{ get; private set; }
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public string LoginName { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<BankAccount> BankAccounts { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; private set; }  

    public void AddBankAccount(BankAccount accountToAdd, IBankAccountValidator bankAccountValidator)
    {
        bankAccountValidator.Validate(accountToAdd);

        this.BankAccounts.Add(accountToAdd);
    }

    public void AddCreditCard(CreditCard creditCardToAdd, ICreditCardValidator ccValidator)
    {
        ccValidator.Validate(creditCardToAdd);

        this.CreditCards.Add(creditCardToAdd);
    }

    public void UpdateEmail(string NewEmail)
    {
        this.Email = NewEmail;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, i see nobody really answered your question. Well, at least I don't think saying "use an ORM" is a solution. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example of Repository interface from [S#arp Architecture](http://sharparchitecture.net/) project. It is similar to [PoEAA Data Mapper](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) because it used to CRUD operations also.

```
public interface IRepositoryWithTypedId<T, IdT>
{
    T Get(IdT id);    
    IList<T> GetAll();    
    IList<T> FindAll(IDictionary<string, object> propertyValuePairs);    
    T FindOne(IDictionary<string, object> propertyValuePairs);    
    T SaveOrUpdate(T entity);    
    void Delete(T entity);    
    IDbContext DbContext { get; }
}
```

As you can see, there is no update method for specific properties of an entity. The whole entity is provided as an argument into the method `SaveOrUpdate`.

When properties of your domain entity are being updated you should tell your [Unit of Work](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) that entity is 'dirty' and should be saved into storage (e.g. database)

[image: PoEAA Unit of Work]

You should not pollute your Person object with information about updated fields but it is needed to track information if entity is updated.

There might be methods of the class `DomainObject` which tell 'Unit of Work' if entity is 'new', 'dirty' or 'deleted'. And then your UoW itself might invoke proper repository methods - 'SaveOrUpdate' or 'Delete'.

Despite the fact that modern ORM Frameworks like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) or [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) have their own implementations of 'Unit of Work', people tend to write their own wrappers/ abstractions for them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, much appreciated!. 

Unfortunately, I still don't know how my person object can make the repository aware that a credit card was added and needs to be saved or that the email was updated and it only needs to be updated.     My Person object contains many other objects but in reality  they map to multiple data tables.

Comment: Do you use any ORM? What do you use to interact with DB in your repositories?

There can be two options generally:
**1st** -> If CreditCard is a child of the aggregate root and makes no sense without Person, then you should update/create Person (Persons table in DB) and then update collection of CreditCards (CreditCards table in DB) with PersonRepository. **2nd** -> If CreditCard is an entity that makes sense without Person, then you should create/update CreditCard with it's own CreditCardRepository and then create/update person with PersonRepository.

Comment: Thanks again for your comments.   In your 1st scenario what i'm having difficulty understanding is how the PersonRepsitory knows that a credit card was added and needs to be inserted.  Or how a credit card was modified and needs to be updated.

Comment: In any case Person knows that it was modified. The simplest way is to remove all linked CreditCards and then save current state. In my project I retrieve data from DB as part of Update method in order to check which 'children' should be added, updated, removed or skipped.

Answer (score 0):

What I'm doing to solve this problem, is adding an interface to my domain objects:

```
interface IDirtyTracker {
    bool IsDirty {get;}
    void MarkClean();
    void MarkDirty();
}
```

The base `DomainObject` class could implement `IDirtyTracker`, and then repositories etc. could use `IsDirty` to check if it's dirty or clean.

In each setter that makes a change:

```
void SetValue() {
    this._value = newValue;
    this.MarkDirty();
}
```

This does not give you fine grain checking, but it's a simple way to avoid some unnecessary updates at the repository level.

To make this a little easier, a `GetPropertiesToIncludeInDirtyCheck` method could be added, which would retrieve a list of properties which need to be checked.

```
interface IDirtyTracker {
    IENumerable<Object> GetPropertiesToIncludeInDirtyCheck();
}
```